# Как поменять фоновую картинку в активити на API меньше 16?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-layout

я знаю как поменять с помощью команды `relativeLayout.setBackground(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.picture1));`
но эта команда требует `API 16`, а мне нужно, чтобы поддерживался `Android 2.3`. Может есть другой вариант?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть

```
int sdkVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if(sdkVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    relativeLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background) );
} else {
    relativeLayout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background));
}
```

Comment: смысл закрывать вопрос? Если ответ верный, то пользователи больше не будут спрашивать это. Правильно?

Comment: (я имел ввиду поставить галку -правильный ответ) а можно без лишних if просто указать relativeLayout.setBackgroundDrawable?

Comment: лучше так оставить на самом деле)